# Using Google Earth server data with custom GIS app

Tags: c++, google-earth-enterprise

I have implemented my own GIS-like app that is able to show tiled data (Bing & Esri tiles for example) and georeferenced images. However, customer wants to use the app in an offline environment with their Google Earth server.

Is this possible?

I tried to find a way to retrieve data from such server, but all the examples are using Google-based  solutions for client side. My application is written from scratch in C++/OpenGL.

Comment: some information http://www.opengee.org/geedocs/5.2.1/answer/6078457.html